# Review audit failed for low quality posts?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, low-quality-posts

I reviewed this late answer as `No Action Needed`.  https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/12293473

As the question was about the migration tool and the answer provides the link for the same. But it was saying the review audit failed. I am not sure whether that was a very low quality answer?

```
You have made too many incorrect reviews.
 For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: 
https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/12293473.

Come back in 7 days to continue reviewing.
```

I  don't think this was a very low quality answer. Can anyone explain what's wrong with it?

[image]

Comment: This is a link-only answer and thus VLQ. If the link dies the answer is completely useless.

Comment: Even it claimed as a VLQ, there should be some other way to handle it. Blocking a active user for a week, may not be a good solution. PS: Its not a `spam post` or `unsalvageable` and i have not reviewed it with out reading through it.

Comment: @Gangaraju You're only blocked from reviewing, not anything else, you wouldn't have been blocked for *just this*, it takes multiple failures, the post *is* spam, the fact that you read it through and still didn't act on it doesn't excuse failing to act on it; if anything, your actions demonstrate a fundamental lack of understanding of the purpose of the queue, so having a week to do some research in how to review properly is likely going to be good for you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It was a late answer to a question that already had a detailed answer, and the answer could not stand on its own without that link. The English in it lacked punctuation and was almost unintelligible. All that combines to make this a poor answer that should be downvoted at best. Certainly, some action was needed on this.

You didn't have the context on this, but that same link was promoted by this user in multiple places, making this most likely spam for that site. Multiple users flagged this answer as "very low quality", along with the other one that promoted their site, and they were deleted as a result.

Seems like a decent audit to me.

Answer (score 8):

If you are only reading the answer, it might appear to have a shriver of an answer (by SE standards):

> ...convert sql to laravel migration

Once you read the question, however, it becomes obvious that it clearly doesn't try to solve the problem:

> convert Laravel migrations to SQL scripts

There's two things here:

1. It is offering a conversion in the opposite direction
2. Even if 1 was not an issue, restating the question does not make something an answer.

Therefore it is a low quality (grammar, punctuation, length), link-only answer. You should be able to deduce that it should be deleted even without knowing the spammy background that [Brad Larson mentions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322723/6083675).